# How can I view detailed DNS server information with Windows XP?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, windows-xp

The DNS management console included in RSAT for Windows 7 displays more data about DNS records, such as the timestamp of the record, than the standard view in Windows XP. Is it possible to get this information from the management console in the console provided in the adminpack.msi package for Windows XP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my coworkers just found the answer. While it doesn't appear to be possible to add a column for the timestamp, opening the "View" menu and putting a checkmark next to "Advanced" will make the information visible in the Properties dialog for a record.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at more details of [dns server](http://www.bestwebhostings.net/dns-server) here

Comment: Including relevant information and not just a link is appreciated :)